# VS 2012 RC broken references not visible

Tags: visual-studio

In VS 2012 RC, much has been discussed about its lack of color and overall 'grayness'. Does a reference exist on what icons/ color are used to denote broken references? For example, I am getting a major exception thrown where my MVC4 app (.NET 4.5) suddenly cannot find System.Web.Http. I added this reference, and now have a few other broken references causing problems. However, they do not show as broken in the typical icon that I am used to in VS 2008 or VS 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your question about a broken project or how unresolvable references will show?

Bad references should show up with a small exclamation point in a yellow triangle next to them.

Questions about a broken project would require more details about what is happening.

Comment: Question is about unresolvable references. When I opened the project again recently, I saw the small yellow triangle for a few moments- similar to VS 2010 but much fainter. After a minute, they eventually cleared up and it builds/runs. However, w/ the behavior initially, only the black rectangle glyph was visible, so I was hoping I did not have to guess and add each one back individually. Thanks.